# How to get Start Time of currently running SSRS Subscriptions

Tags: ssrs-2017, reportserver

Can anyone help me in getting the currently running SSRS Subscription report `Start Time`.

I queried `dbo.Notifications` table, but the columns `NotificationEntered` , `ProcessStart` and `ProcessAfter` is quite confusing.

Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try this below query to get running subscription details

```
select c.ItemID as ReportId,
       c.Name,
       c.Path,
       s.SubscriptionID,
       s.LastStatus,
       s.LastRunTime,
       s.DeliveryExtension
from ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions s
inner join ReportServer.dbo.Catalog c
on s.Report_OID=c.ItemID 
where s.LastStatus like '%Pending%'
```

`LastRunTime` column is subscription start time.
`LastStatus` column is status description of subscription.